# Do all OpenCL drivers come with the IntelOneAPI compiler

Tags: opencl, intel, intel-oneapi

I would like to ask if the Intel OneAPI compiler from the Intel OneApi toolkit comes with the required OpenCL drivers for the relevant processors that support SPIR capable OpenCL runtimes